# Catching different TypeErrors

Tags: python, error-handling, typeerror

I have a dictionary that has three different kinds of key-value pairs in it. The values are one of the three shapes: A dictionary, null, or an integer, e.g.:

```
dic = {"range" : {"val": 1, "size": 2},
       "length" : {"val": 5, "radius": 1},
       "power": null,
       "current": 5}
```

I am using a try-except block, with the dictionary value as default, and want to catch the TypeError for null and integer separately. For value null, it gives "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable" and for an integer, it gives "TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable". How do I catch these errors in different exceptions? I am looping through the keys of interest in the dictionary and an example of what I am currently doing is below, however it catches both errors as they are both TypeError:

```
for kw in list_of_keys:
    try:
        val_test = dic[kw]['val']
    except TypeError:
        val_test = dic[kw]
```

I would like to catch errors similar to the following:

```
for kw in list_of_keys:
    try:
        val_test = dic[kw]['val']
    except TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable:
        val_test = dic[kw]
    except TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable:
        val_test = "Not implemented / Not given yet"
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: There's only one kind of exception involved. You could try to match the message, but this is a case where it is *not* easier to ask forgiveness than to ask permission. Just look at the value of `dic[kw]` before trying to do anything with it.

Comment: You mean `None`, not `null`, right?

Comment: You can't. You can catch `TypeError` and then check what the argument says, though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exceptions are for, well, exceptional results. Here, a `None` or `int` value seems just as valid as a `dict` value, so you should just look at `dic[kw]` before assuming it is a `dict`.

```
for kw in list_of_keys:
    v = dic[kw]
    if v is None:
        val_test = "Not implemented / Not given yet"
    else:
        try:
            val_test = v['val']
        except TypeError:
            val_test = v
```

Once you've determined if `v` is `None` or not, *then* you can try to index it and assume it is an `int` on a `TypeError`.

Comment: Thank you, it is a smart way of going around the issue! In my real case, I have ~80% of values as dicts and just a few as integers. I wrote null instead of None, because the data is pulled from an API to JSON and it gives value of null. Nonetheless it seems to deal with the problem.

Comment: The JSON contains the string "null", but once you decode it, you have the value `None` in the `dict` you are actually working with.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `type()` keyword to check if a variable is `Integer` or `NoneType` and use try-except accordingly.

Otherwise to check if a variable is subscriptable:

```
from collections.abc import Iterable

if isinstance(theElement, Iterable):
    # iterable
else:
    # not iterable
```

You can also use `hasattr(myObj, '__getitem__')` to check this for objects with `__getitem__` method such as dict.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.get()` to check `None` or `boolen` and `isinstance` method to check if it is an `integer`.

```
for kw in list_of_keys:

    val = dic.get(kw)
    
    if not val:
       val = "NoneType Error"
    
    elif isinstance(val,int):
       val = "Integer Error"
    
    else:
        val=val['val']
```